# How to sample instance of a class randomly from a tensorflow dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have a tensorflow dataset populated with images and labels ([class_label,char_idx]). I want to create a refrence matrix whose each entry should have a random image taken from each class and char_idx combination. I tried to accomplish this by creating a reference dataset matrix 'ref_ds' in which each entry is a filtered dataset based on the class_label and char_idx combination. However, filter is not working correctly, it results in inaccurate number of samples for each combination and since the dataset is large it hangs the kernel.

Dataset is very large (162010 entries) and I need to find a solution that is fast in the training step. I just want to have a random sample of each class and character combination (which is the label) while in the training. Keeping all the images in the list of matrix results in memory runout problem. Please suggest the best way to do this.

```
ref_ds = [[None for j in range(len(affects))] for i in range(len(ids))]
   
for ch_idx in range(num_characters):
    for c in range(num_classes):
        
        ds = train_ds.filter(lambda x,y,a=c,i=ch_idx: tf.greater(tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.equal(y,[a,i]), tf.float32)), tf.constant(0.)) ) 

        ds = ds.map(lambda x,y: x)
        ref_ds[ch_idx][c] = ds
```

Comment: Have you tried `ds.shuffle(num_shuffle).take(num_samples)`

Comment: I mananged to get correct number of instances by following: ``` ds = train_ds.filter(lambda x,y,a=c,i=ch_idx: tf.greater(tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.equal(y,[a,i]), tf.float32)), tf.constant(1.)) ) ``` However, the processing is extremely slow; it seems either hard-disk is failing or this process is too resource intensive.